# Can I continue a bash script after rake task?

Tags: bash, rake, rake-task

I made a script that can migrate jira data to redmine but when i run i it only runs 1 rake task and not both, is it possible to continue your script after you ran a rake task? Here is a piece  my code:

```
#2: Run migration test
while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do
   echo -ne "Test Migration will start in: $secs\033[0K\r"
   sleep 1
   : $((secs--))
done

rake jira_migration:test_all_migrations RAILS_ENV="production"

#3: Run Migration

while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do
   echo -ne "Test Migration will start in: $secs\033[0K\r"
   sleep 1
   : $((secs--))
done

rake jira_migration:do_all_migrations RAILS_ENV="production"

printf 'Migration is completed!'
```

Rake file task:

```
desc "Tests all parsers!"
    task :test_all_migrations => [:environment, :pre_conf,
                                  :test_parse_projects,
                                  :test_parse_users,
                                  :test_parse_comments,
                                  :test_parse_issues] do
      puts "All parsers was run! :-)"
    end
```

Comment: If it stops it's likely because of some kind of error. Do you have any logs? A tool like `rake` doesn't normally prevent other parts of your script from running.

Comment: the rake did run fine and gave no errors it gave : All parsers was run! :-)
which means the rake task ran properly

Comment: I added the lines that will run in the rake file @tadman

Comment: The second `while` loop never runs, by the way; you don't reset the value of `secs` to a non-zero value after the first one.

Comment: What is the evidence that the second task did not run? Does `Migration is completed!` never get displayed?

Comment: @chepner thanks for the notice, I fixed it by putting || : at the end of both of the rake commands so it would return true, I also put a couple lines of code in that check if the files that are needed are present . thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kevin It sounds like you are using `set -e`; consider *not* using it for exactly this reason. (Or at least figure out why `rake` has a non-zero exit status.)